# Spotify WebAPI URL Request Syntax

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, spotify

After last update about authorization it's still possible do get request for tracks? Before the update I've this request URL:

> https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4jTiyLlOJVJj3mCr7yfPQD

But now it returns:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "No token provided"
  }
}
```

How can I do the call now with auth token? What is the syntax I've to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to follow the [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) to get tokens and after that (as noted in "6. Use the access token to access the Spotify Web API") you can then add a "Authorization: Bearer <token>" header to your request.

FYI, this is all noted in the API reference for the [Get a Track](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-track/) call you're making, under the "Authorization" section, which is noted as "Required. A valid access token from the Spotify Accounts service: see the Web API Authorization Guide for details."

Comment: I already have auth token but I don't know what is the key to put it in the tracks request url.

Comment: There isn't one. You'll need to add a header. If you've got the token "foo" add an Authorization header with the value "Bearer foo"